почему текст отображается под задним фоном, а не на нём? И как это исправить


body {
  font-family: "Rostov";
  color: #CD2C24;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}

h1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.striped {
  background: linear-gradient( lightblue 80%, gray 20%);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Rostov";
  src: url("../fonts/Rostov.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  z-index: 2;
}
<center>
  <div class="striped"></div>
  <h1>Какие бывают технические зависимости, и как от них избавиться</h1>
</center>




Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Ну, у вас h1 находится вне div. Потому он отображается под ним.


body {
  font-family: "Rostov";
  color: #CD2C24;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

div.striped {
  height: 100vh;
  /* z-index: 1; */
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue 80%, gray 20%);
}
<center>
  <div class="striped">
    <h1>Какие бывают технические зависимости, и как от них избавиться</h1>
  </div>
</center>



P.S. По возможности, не используйте center - это устаревший тег
